# conditional statement returning value in input box

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following.
input box type number for a number rating of the risk likelihood
input box type number for a number rating of the risk Consequence.
input box type number for a number rating of the risk rating which is predetermined by a matrix with values ranging from 1-9.
input box for the rating of the risk level.

what i need is,

if the value in the the risk rating area is between 1 & 2 the risk level area should display "low"

if the value in the the risk rating area is between 3 & 6 the risk level area should display "medium"

if the value in the the risk rating area is between 7 & 9 the risk level area should display "high".

how do i write in an input box if the above mentioned conditions have been met.

the following is my code:

```
function getRiskRate(z){
    var z=document.getElementById("Risk_rating").value;
        return(z);

}
getRiskRate();

function Rate(z){
    var z=document.getElementById("Risk_rating").value;
    getRiskRate();
        if(z>1 || z<=2){
            document.getElementById('mySeverity').value='Low';
            } else if(z>2 || z<=6){
                document.getElementById('mySeverity').value='Medium';
                } else if (z>6 || z<=9){
                    document.getElementById('mySeverity').value='High';
                        }else{
                            document.getElementById('mySeverity').value='value not defined';
                        }
}
Rate();
```

Comment: ...and is there a question here?  Are you just looking for pointers on how to make your code better, or is there an active problem?

Comment: You have to call `Rate()` if someone changes the input.

Comment: Thanks Guys appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getRiskRate(z) {
  var z = document.getElementById("Risk_rating").value;
  return (z);

}

function Rate() {
  var z = getRiskRate();
  
  if (z > 1 && z <= 2) {
    document.getElementById('mySeverity').innerHTML = 'Low';
  } else if (z > 2 && z <= 6) {
    document.getElementById('mySeverity').innerHTML = 'Medium';
  } else if (z > 6 && z <= 9) {
    document.getElementById('mySeverity').innerHTML = 'High';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mySeverity').innerHTML = 'value not defined';
  }
}

document.getElementById("Risk_rating").onkeyup = Rate;
```

```html
Input: <input id="Risk_rating"></input>
<div id="mySeverity"></div>
```

1. Attach an event handler like `document.getElementById("Risk_rating").onkeyup = Rate;` so that this function is called every time someone types in the box.
2. Your logical operators weren't working properly. Anytime someone types a number greater than 1, the risk would be displayed as low. You need to switch to `&&`.

Comment: Thank you so much Katie. I will try your solution now.